# CSS or Javascript?

Tags: css, menu

I'm having difficulty centering my mega menu dropdown here:
http://drupal.scienceworld.ca

The dropdown that unfolds on hover: should I position using CSS, or is there some behaviour of JS that I should be tweaking instead? If CSS is the issue, how should I best keep that dropdown centred in the browser as browser size changes?

Comment: This is too localized, not at all useful for others, am voting to close, from next time paste your code try to make a fiddle..and btw your link is dead

Comment: Mr. Alien: my apologies. I'm rather new here. It seems I've come to the wrong place to look for advice. I will close this.

Comment: you want the menu take 100% browser width?

Comment: Tom: I want the dropdown menu to be centred in the browser, at any browser resolution, like so:http://cl.ly/image/050y2H012H01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After take a closed look to your site, I see your plugin is setting some styles for the hidden div (the visit submenu):
For example in my 1366x780 browser size I got:

```
position: absolute;
width: 960px;
display: none;
top: 158px;
left: 580.5px;
```

**This is what is going on:**
The plugin calculate the absolute position for the hidden element (I think you are using qTip plugin), and this calculation is based on the menu hovered item (visit on this case).

**Possible Solution**:
Instead of using that qTip, you can write a simple jquery plugin code for horizontally center the div based on the parent div width:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
   this.css("position","absolute");
   this.css("display", "visible"
   this.css("top", "158px");
   this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
   return this;
}
```

Use it like this:

$(element).center();

**Note:** You should use this on hover event in the menu item.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I guess I may also need to re-style the width per each media query?

Comment: I got a better way to solve your problem, check edit